# Chamar outro Layout

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Ao colocar e-mail e senha o app deve chamar outro layout.
Só que não estou conseguindo fazer isso...

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, R.layout.activity_estado);
startActivity(intent);
```

Informa o seguinte erro: 
Cannot resolve constructor 'Intent'(model.Principal, int);

Confesso que sou iniciante em Android.

Obrigado desde já

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você está colocando o *layout* no lugar onde é necessário inserir uma classe. Basicamente neste seu caso, necessário você terá que criar uma outra `Activity`, por exemplo `ActivityEstado`, com o seu *layout* `activity_estado.xml`. Logo depois inserir ela no seu `manifest.xml`. Depois de feito, você pode trocar de tela usando o método `startActivity()`. Veja:

**Main**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityEstado.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

**manifest.xml:**

```
<activity android:name=".ActivityEstado"/>
```

Veja aqui na documentação do Android [tudo sobre `Intent`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)'s e aqui no artigo [Android Intents - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidIntent/article.html)

Answer (score 3):

Ao invés de

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, R.layout.activity_estado);
startActivity(intent);
```

Use

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityEstado.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

O segundo parametro do Intent é a Classe, e não o layout.

Comment: Erro: Unknown class: 'activity_estado'.

Comment: Certo, isso eu compreendo. Quero saber onde é que layout entra nisso... :(